# How to track links that certain app accesses?

Tags: applications, cache, url

I always get concerned about backing up data that is relatively large, for the sake of bandwidth, which is kind of expensive in my area, really expensive.

For example, when I installed "Google Translate", I manually downloaded the language packs that I need, so I could install them whenever I want. I found the link browsing forums
[http://dl.google.com/translate/offline/v3/r1/*lang*.zip](http://dl.google.com/translate/offline/v3/r1/%2alang%2a.zip)

And **now** I've installed Google Text-To-Speech, and I wish to download High Quality voice data.
I haven't found any information about this on the internet.

So maybe you guys could help me, and tell me of possible ways to know, what url's or uri's are being accessed by a certain app while downloading cache or even just connecting for something?

Any advises appreciated

Comment: 10 hours later, no answer so far :( been browsing all day to find a way... still stuck

Comment: I've came out with some workaround to get the voice data. However, I haven't been able to find out how to track links that apps request, particularly Download Manager app. Anyone interested in the way I backed up the voice data, just ask me :)